# Debug on Visual Studio with custom url (but in local machine)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I want to debug in Visual Studio Community 2013 but using a custom url www.blablabla.com instead of localhost:xxxx for routing debugging purposes.

I don't want to use another server besides my own pc VS one, I just want to change the url.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your host files locally to override DNS.

```
 c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

Change something like:

```
127.128.0.0.1  www.yourdomain.com
```

Once this is modified, I would do a DNS flush, and I would think this should work.

Here is an in depth article.
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file